# Duplicate Visual Studio Code Window for "code ." command

Tags: visual-studio-code

#### Question

Why when I typed "code ." over command prompt, it will automatic open two visual studio code window?

#### Screen

https://prnt.sc/tvhjy6

Answer (score 1):

Use

```
code -a .
```

to add the folder to the last active window.

See `code --help` for more options.

Comment: mhutter, thanks for taking your time to answer my question. Is it normal if I type "code ." and it open two windows automatically?

Comment: Yes, the default behaviour is to open a new VS Code window each time you open a folder or file with `code ...`.